# GNU make and hg: which file can be used to decide my target is outdated?

Tags: mercurial, makefile, gnu-make

Assume a Mercurial repository `foo`. Furthermore assume a `make` job run from `crontab` that is supposed to update a bundle of everything from revision `0` to the `tip` whenever something changes within the repository. Let us assume `GNUmakefile` is part of the working directory of our repository `foo` as well.

Which file under `foo/.hg` can I rely on as dependency in order to decide whether to run `hg bundle` or not?

Answer (score 3):

I think you could do worse than to look at `.hg/store/00changelog.i`. This contains the index for changeset metadata in your repository (for very small repositories, it also contains the corresponding data). Note that this doesn't say anything about the contents of the working directory! But that shouldn't matter if you just want a complete bundle.

This does depend on the contents of the `.hg/requires` file, though. In particular, the repository would at least need the `store` flag.

Comment: Hey @djc, thanks for the answer. I'll check it out and get back to you. +1 for taking the time to answer. And yes, the working directory contents won't matter (except for the `GNUmakefile`).

Answer (score 1):

I *suppose*, direct working with files inside `.hg` is **not** The Right Thing (tm)

If "...whenever something changes within the repository" you have new changeset(s), or old changeset-id may be changed (rewritten history?). In this case, output of native Mercurial commands will change and you can compare results of previous run and current and make choice

`hg id -i`, for example, in commit-hook can write into (ignored) file in Working Directory of repository or in just *some file*, which you crontab-job check ater

Comment: `hg id -i` wouldn't be a very good choice, since it reflects the working dir revision rather than tip. I guess `hg id -irtip` could work, though. On the other hand, I don't think that looking at the mtime for the changelog index is that bad for this kind of thing.

Comment: @djc -yes, I forgot to test tip. For me, using "legal" ways is *more natural* way (only). From other side, something like [MercurialRev](https://bitbucket.org/JPlenert/mercurialrev) may be also good choice